# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf parsing error in loop

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf views gives me parsing error when I try to use index variable inside array like this:

```
<tr th:each="cdItem, stat : *{commonDataItems}">      
      <td th:text=${stat.index}>Index</td>      
      <td> <input type="text" th:field=*{commonDataItems[__${stat.index}__].value>Value</td>    
</tr>
```

This `<td th:text=${stat.index}>Index</td>` line is for testing purposes and it gives the right index value, but next line `<td> <input type="text" th:field=*{commonDataItems[__${stat.index}__].value>Value</td>` gives parsing error.
Error message is:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "*{commonDataItems[__${stat.index}__].value" (common)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:238) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:79) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Are you missing quotes or is that just a typo: `th:field="*{commonDataItems[__${stat.index}__].value"`

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Not too proud of myself now though :) You can write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ta, you just needed some fresh eyes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing quotes! `th:field="*{commonDataItems[__${stat.index}__].value"`

So:

```
<tr th:each="cdItem, stat : *{commonDataItems}">      
      <td th:text=${stat.index}>Index</td>      
      <td> <input type="text" th:field="*{commonDataItems[__${stat.index}__].value">Value</td>    
</tr>
```